# Change Minecraft Drowned sounds with resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I'm trying to change the Drowned sound effects in Minecraft Java edition 1.18, but they don't change. What file structure and files are needed change the sounds?  I tried putting the files under both

/resource_pack_folder/assets/minecraft/sounds/entity/drowned
/resource_pack_folder/assets/minecraft/sounds/mob/drowned

The files I put are ambient.ogg, ambient_water.ogg, death.ogg, death_water.ogg, hurt.ogg, and hurt_water.ogg.

These are named according to the list of sound effects for the Drowned found in the wiki:

[https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Drowned#:~:text=a%20player%20underwater.-,Sounds,-Sound](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Drowned#:%7E:text=a%20player%20underwater.-,Sounds,-Sound)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have not added the "sounds.json" file under this directory:

```
<packname>/assets/minecraft/
```

The structure of this file should be like this example:

```
{
    "entity.drowned.ambient": {
        "subtitle": "drowning something",
        "replace": false,
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/something",
                "volume": 1,
                "weight": 1,
                "pitch": 1,
                "attenuation_distance": 16,
                "stream": false,
                "preload": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Basically, this example sounds.json file does the following:

```
"entity.drowned.ambient"
```

is the original sound to replace.

```
"subtitle": "drowning something"
```

the subtitle that shows if you have them enabled

```
"sounds": [
    {
        "name": "custom/something"
```

the path to your sound; in my example I would put my sound under

```
soundpack.zip/assets/minecraft/sounds/custom/something.ogg
```

(omit .ogg in json file)

```
"volume": 1,
"weight": 1,
"pitch": 1,
```

I have not messed with these, but you can if you like

```
"attenuation_distance": 16,
```

the distance from the source that you can hear the sound, in blocks

```
"stream": false,
"preload": false
```

I haven't messed with these either

If you want to make more changes to other sounds, you just continue the json structure. You can use https://jsoneditoronline.org to easily create, edit, and export .json documents in code or tree mode.